# Find Amicable number for given number in shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a shell script which will find amicable numbers for given numbers which are entered by user. If found it will print the amicable no else will print "No". I am getting the expected output but it is taking some time. It will be very helpful if code is optimize. I am running the code on git bash.

```
declare -A input
echo "enter the no of inputs"
read n
echo "enter the numbers"
for((i=0;i<n;i++))
do
    read n1
    input[$i]=$n1
done
findDivisors() {
    sum=1
    sqrtNo=$(echo "$1" | awk '{printf "%.0f\n",sqrt($1)}')
    for((i=2;i<=$sqrtNo;i++))
    do
        if [ `expr $1 % $i` -eq 0 ]; then
            if [ $i -eq `expr $1 % $i` ]; then
                let sum+=$i
            else
                let sum+=$i+"($1/$i)"
            fi
        fi
    done
    echo "$sum"
}
findAmicableNo() {
    ret=$(findDivisors $1)
    s2=$(findDivisors $ret)
    if [ $s2 -eq $1 ]; then
        echo "Yes, amicable with $ret"
    else
        echo "No"
    fi
}
for i in "${!input[@]}"
do
    findAmicableNo ${input[$i]}
done
```

Comment: You are using the shell-external program `awk`. Which external programs do you want or not want to use?

Comment: Note that using `expr` is bad practice; it's very slow compared to shell-builtin math, which would be written as `if (( $1 % i == 0 )); then` with bash-only syntax, or `if [ $(( $1 % i )) -eq 0 ]` for POSIX compatibility. Then again, you shouldn't use `$( )` (or backticks) _at all_ in performance-sensitive code, so there's a lot here that's not well-written if speed is desired.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about how to improve working code belong on [codereview.se], not Stack Overflow (which is for narrow, specific questions about _broken_ code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using `awk` in your script, you may as well write the script entirely for `awk`. This is a lot faster.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { print "enter the no of inputs"
        getline n
        print "enter the numbers"
        i = 0
      }
      {
        input[i++] = $0
        if (n <= i) nextfile
      }
END   {
        for (i in input) findAmicableNo(input[i])
      }
function findAmicableNo(n)
{
    ret = findDivisors(n)
    s2 = findDivisors(ret)
    if (s2 == n)
        print "Yes, amicable with "ret
    else
        print "No"
}
function findDivisors(n)
{
    sum = 1
    sqrtNo = sqrt(n)
    for (i = 2; i <= sqrtNo; i++)
        if (n % i == 0 )
            if (i == n % i)
                sum += i
            else
                sum += i+n/i
    return sum
}
```

Comment: thankyou for your help, code is now optimize. I am new to `awk` and it will be very helpful if you explain me the usability of `nextfile` statement in this code.

Comment: Yes, this is somewhat unusual. I'm using `nextfile` here to stop reading input lines after `n`  inputs; provided that there are no further files named on the command line, `awk` then executes the `END` rule.